# VS2017 debugger gives wrong value of static variable when debugging c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Today i stumbled over a weird debugging situation.

I have 2 files (FileA.cpp and FileB.cpp in this example). In both files i declare a static variable named `static int TestVar;`

Both Files have a Function to modify the static variable:

```
void ModifyTestVarFileA();
void ModifyTestVarFileB();
```

Now i start debugging and step into the function `ModifyTestVarFileA()`.

I add the variable `TestVar` to the watch window.
It shows 0, as expected.
after stepping through the code, behind the assignment, the variable is still 0.
Then i step further, into `ModifyTestVarFileB()`.
There the variable is still 0.
But after the assignment of `TestVar ='B';` the value changes correctly to 66.

When i edit my code, so that those two variables are named different, it behaves as expected.

Greetings Wolfgang

**ConsoleApplication1.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "FileA.h"
#include "FileB.h"
int main()
{
   ModifyTestVarFileA();
   ModifyTestVarFileB();
}
```

**FileA.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "FileA.h"

static int TestVar;

void ModifyTestVarFileA()
{
    TestVar ='A';
}
```

**FileB.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "FileB.h"

static int TestVar;

void ModifyTestVarFileB()
{
    TestVar ='B';
}
```

**FileA.h**

```
#pragma once
void ModifyTestVarFileA();
```

**FileB.h**

```
#pragma once
void ModifyTestVarFileB();
```

Comment: What "two variables"? Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem. Aside: there are possibly known issues with Visual Studio but I can't find a relevant question.

Comment: I modified the question and added the content of my sourcefiles to it...

Comment: Perhaps the variable has been optimised out of the code.

Comment: Is there a reason you expect `0` when you do not initialize the variables?

Comment: @crashmstr are `static` variables implicitly initilaised to `0`?

Comment: Wether or not they are initialized or not, when i add the variable to the watch list and the assignment of 'A' or 'B' takes place, the watch list should reflect this assignment. No matter if the initial value was 0, or 0xCCCC (as i have seen it often somewhere else)...

Comment: @WeatherVane Doh. My mistake. Too much working with other languages... :(

Comment: @WolfgangRoth When and where are you when you are checking the watch value for the variables? I don't know that the debugger's watch window can differentiate well between the two unless you are executing code in the file where it is defined.

Comment: I thought, i described it very well, what i did, and what i expect the watch window to show... While in `ModifyTestVarA` the value should change from 0 to 65, and while in `ModifyTestVarB` the value should change from 0 to 66

Comment: So after stepping over `TestVar ='A';` and before leaving the scope of `ModifyTestVarFileA()`, `TestVar` is `0`? Or is it after leaving `ModifyTestVarFileA` and before stepping into `ModifyTestVarFileB`?

Comment: the first one is correct - because when leaving the function, the variable is out of scope, as i am back in `main()`. Maybe it depends on the compiler, and you get a different result, so that in `ModifyTestVarFileB` you see the value being 65 and not being changed to 66...

Comment: I've done a test in VS 2019. If I set a breakpoint *in the functions*, the values are correct. *Outside* of the scope of those files, the "watched" `TestVar` depends on which definition the debugger has picked of the two.

Comment: @crashmstr: i disagree, tried it with breakpoints enabled and reselected the variables from code, but does not help on my side...

Comment: If the actual value in the variable is incorrect in that file after assignment, that would seem to be a very serious bug in VS 2017. If it is just the watch window (have you tried writing the value to console to confirm), then it would seem to just be an inconvenience.

Comment: I slightly changed my code signature and returen the adress (int*) of the TestVar. Then i can compare both dereferenced pointer values in main() and voila, the memory location shows the correct value... So just a bit of nuisance

Comment: Indeed, as crashmstr said, the VS  watch window cannot clearly identify static variables with the same name. Static global variables are stored in the static storage area. They are initialized before the `main` function and destroyed after the `main` function. The compiler distinguishes static variables with the same name according to the address, but it is difficult for the watch window. Therefore, it is not recommended that you use static variables with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like the "big" discussion here is over.

So I want to answer my question as follows:

You have to take care that all of your static (in german we say module global) variables are named differently when using Visual Studio and want to debug / watch them in the watch window. VS is not able to distinguish variables named equally in different source code files.